# How to get a value of an Enum type from a GuestStatus object - Google Script

Tags: google-apps-script, google-calendar-api

I'm trying to get the status for invited Guests for a given Google Calendar Event.

```
// receives and EventGuest object
// https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/calendar/event-guest
function getInviteeStatus(eventguest) {
  var gueststatus,
      guestname = eventguest.getName(),
      guestemail = eventguest.getEmail(),
      guestguestcount = eventguest.getAdditionalGuests(),
      gueststatusObj = eventguest.getGuestStatus(); // returns a GuestStatus object

  // export enum GuestStatus { INVITED, MAYBE, NO, OWNER, YES } - this is from some docs I found
  // how do I convert the GuestStatus object to a string that represents the status?
  //gueststatus = ???

  return [guestname, guestemail, guestguestcount, gueststatus]
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to retrieve `INVITED, MAYBE, NO, OWNER, YES` as a string. If my understanding is correct, how about this modification?

#### From :

```
gueststatusObj = eventguest.getGuestStatus();
Logger.log("%s, %s", gueststatusObj, typeof gueststatusObj) // INVITED, object
```

#### To :

```
gueststatusObj = eventguest.getGuestStatus().toString();
Logger.log("%s, %s", gueststatusObj, typeof gueststatusObj) // INVITED, string
```

#### Note :

- In this modified script, `INVITED` was used as a sample.

If I misunderstand your question, I'm sorry.

Comment: OMG, it was that easy.  I couldn't see the forest for the trees I guess.  You wouldn't believe how many crazy things I tried. You answer is much appreciated.